# The name Repeater1 does not exist in the current content

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

Im using a masterpage on asp.net c# for the website. (And created an aspx page related to the master page, by hand, not automatically)

I put a repeater control to the page.

Then I couldn't reach to the control by name in codebehind.

The compiling error is : 'The name Repeater1 does not exist in the current content'

Can you please point out my mistake?

Comment: Is this a page that has a "designer" page associated with it? Sometimes for whatever reason my designers would not update with elements from the page.  If you can regenerate that designer it might solve your issue

Comment: You are right! The error is about designer updating. I clicked Project --> Convert to web application. And it worked. Thank You!:)

Comment: Well glad I could help :)  Going to post the above comment as an answer if you don't mind marking it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the designers get out of sync with the aspx pages.  When such a thing occurs, the code behind files become unable to access controls that you have added to your aspx pages and you'll get errors like the one you received.

You can get around this error by regenerating the designer file, as you said Project -> Convert to web application is one way to do it.

One last thing, not sure what version of VS you're using, or if this will help, but there was a hotfix released for VS2010 that is supposed to take care of some occurrences of this problem.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2010/03/05/hotfix-for-issue-with-auto-generated-designer-files-not-adding-controls.aspx